How to attach a cookie from my React Native front-end to the @rails/actioncable WebSocket connection?
I am using the React Native Cookies library to set a cookie on the front-end. I noticed that my Axios client automatically detects and attaches the cookie to all request that occur after the cookie has been set.
Now I need to also attach the cookie to my WebSocket connection which uses @rails/actioncable. I was hoping that it would work out of the box similarly to Axios, however, that doesn't seem to be the case. I scoured the documentation but couldn't find anything regarding this, which makes me think it's either very simple or impossible with @rails/actioncable.

You might want to read up on the differences between websockets and normal HTTP. While you can send a cookie along with the handshake request to establish a websocket since that's a normal HTTP request. After that setting the cookies on the client will not do anything as you're communicating through a persistent duplex connection in a completely different protocol.

@max I am getting the cookie before establishing the WebSocket connection, and once established, I won't need to update the cookie. I just need to figure out how to pass the cookie during the WebSocket connection establishment.

@Onyx Did you figure this out?
